# I cannot control muti-thread with Cucumber parallel execution

Tags: automation, parallel-processing, cucumber, testng, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have configured Cucumber parallel execution successfully, but by default, 10 threads will be created at a time. So I tried maven command with **-Ddataproviderthreadcount=2** and it worked. But when I tried define this option in POM file, it didn't work.

My POM:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0-M5</version>
<configuration>
    <parallel>both</parallel>
    <threadCount>2</threadCount>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>integration-test</goal>
            <goal>verify</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <properties>
                <property>
                    <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                    <value>2</value>
                </property>
            </properties>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
                <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/${test.suite}.xml</suiteXmlFile>
            </suiteXmlFiles>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

My Cucumber test runner:

```
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/resources/features", glue = "StepDefinitions", plugin = "pretty")
class runnerOne extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {
    @Override
    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return super.scenarios();
    }
}
```

My TestNG:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >

<suite name="Suite1" verbose="1">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="Utilities.Listener"></listener>
    </listeners>
    <test name="Test" >
        <classes>
            <class name="TestRunners.runnerOne" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to take full benefit of TestNG with Cucumber, you should try using [BDDTestFactory2](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html#factory-class) which is pure TestNG implementation. It considers each scenario as TestNG test and scenario outline with example as data driven test. So it is supporting different parallel configuration and parameters like thread-count, data provider thread count etc.

In your case you are using cucumber so to support step implementation in cucumber you will require [QAF-Cucumber](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_cucumber.html). Use [BDDTestFactory2](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-configuration.html#factory-class) that supports feature files written in `Gherkin` format or `BDD2` format which is super set of Gherkin.